# npm throws Unknown command: "set-script" when creating new Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nvm

I am trying to create new Ruby on Rails project with:

`rails new project -v 7.0.4 --css=sass --javascript=esbuild --database=mysql`

And I get:

```
...
Add build script
         run  npm set-script build "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets" from "."
Unknown command: "set-script"

Did you mean this?
    npm run-script # Run arbitrary package scripts
...
```

npm version:

```
% npm -v
9.1.2
% which npm
/Users/foo/.nvm/versions/node/v19.1.0/bin/npm
```

Interesting is that `nvm help` doesn't even show `set-script` in "All commands" list.

I am on Mac M2, not sure if relevant.
I didn't find anything on google.

Comment: I have hotfixed this by adding scripts (build and build:css) to packages.json by hand and running yarn build and yarn build:css

Answer (score 2):

set-script has been deprecated as per [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-set-script?v=true)

The below should work

```
npm pkg set scripts.build="esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
```

Comment: Thanks. But how/where can I change the command? This is done by Rails automatically..

Comment: You would have to change the script that you’re using if you need this for future projects. This is not used by rails default default as far as I know